# comparing two identical java byte arrays returns false

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("test".getBytes() == "test".getBytes() ? "same" : "diff");
System.out.println("test".getBytes().equals("test".getBytes()) ? "same" : "diff");
```

In both of those lines `diff` is output. They're the same thing so shouldn't it be `same` that is output?

Comment: Use `java.util.Arrays.equals("test".getBytes(), "test".getBytes())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.compare("test".getBytes(), "test".getBytes()) == 0 ? "same" : "diff");
```